# Mac Ports Python 2.6.6 and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, macports

I apologize if this has been asked but does Tkinter work in Python 2.6.6 when installed with Mac Ports? Or do I need to pass the no_tkinter variant?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of MacPorts `python26 @2.6.6_0` and `tk @8.5.8_0`, Tkinter appears to only work if you don't mind using an X11-based Tk.  There is a `+quartz` variant for the `Tk` port which does not require X11 but it is not yet [supported in 64-bit mode](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/20799), the preferred build and execution architecture on OS X 10.6, and at the moment it seems to not work in 32-bit mode either (`tk @8.5.8_0`). If you don't mind having MacPorts pull in a bunch of `X11` client build dependencies and using `X11` for `Tkinter` applications, the default variant looks like it works OK (lightly tested with OS X 10.6.4 and `python26 @2.6.6_0`).  This applies to `IDLE` as well, since it uses `Tkinter`.  Otherwise, stick to `+no_tkinter` if you can live without `Tkinter` and `IDLE`.

By the way, the [Python 2.6.6 installed by the python.org installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/) (32-bit only) uses either the Apple-supplied `Quartz` Tk 8.4 for OS X 10.4 through 10.6 or it will use an [ActiveState Tcl/Tk 8.4](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) if you have installed it.  MacPorts currently has no provision for using either of them.

Comment: Being new to Macports if this does get resolved do I need to reinstall python 2.6 or is there a way to remove the +no_tkinter variant?

Comment: Once it gets fixed, you'll need to reinstall the python26 port: `sudo port selfupdate ; sudo port install tk +quartz ; sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants python26 -no_tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

pytkinter 2.4.6 is the latest version available on macports and works with python 2.4

- http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/python/py-tkinter/Portfile

Comment: They have py25-tkinter which is a stub. Tkinter is now built with python25. So I guess then there is no Tkinter support for 2.6.6 with Mac Ports?

Comment: Yeah missed that stub. But I have not seen Tkinter support for 2.6.6 in Mac Ports

Comment: For Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.x ports, MacPorts includes Tkinter/tkinter in the base `pythonx.x` port.  But see my answer for issues with it.